# DataTable width is going beyond a panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, datatables

Good day everybody.

Im new on ASP.Net MVC 4, Im using DataTable plugin for my table and Im encountering the following problems.
 1. DataTable Width is going beyond the width of the panel that contained it.
 2. It didn't generate a child row that will supposedly show the columns that will not fit in the panel's width.

Any help will be appreciated.

Here is my code for my table (html)

```
<div class="modal" role="dialog" id="modalCustomerDetails_Location"><!--Modal for Customer Details - Location-->
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h3 class="modal-title"><img class="crud" src="~/Images/profile.png" />Customer's Location</h3>
                </div><!--Modal Header-->
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group row well" id="wellCustomerName_Transaction">
                        <label class="control-label col-lg-3">Customer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-lg-9">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control col-lg-12" value="Quiel Cuevas" disabled />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="panel panel-green ">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <h4 class="panel-title">Customer's Transaction</h4>
                        </div><!--Panel heading-->
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table id="tblCustomersLocation" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Location Name</th>
                                <th>Location Type</th>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>Area</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th>Phone 1</th>
                                <th>Phone 2</th>
                                <th>Fax No.</th>
                                <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Mandaluyong</td>
                            <td>Residential</td>
                            <td>Pleasant Hills......</td>
                            <td>NCR</td>
                            <td>quiel@yahoo.com.ph</td>
                            <td>09090909090</td>
                            <td>09909090909</td>
                            <td>123123123</td>
                            <td>
                                <a href='#' data-toggle="modal">Contacts</a> |
                                <a href='#' data-toggle="modal">Transactions</a> |
                                <a href='#' data-toggle="modal">Issued Item</a> |
                            </td>
                        </tr>

                    </table>
                        </div><!--Panel Body-->
                    </div>

                </div> <!--Modal Body-->
            </div><!--Modal Content-->
        </div><!--Modal Dialog-->
    </div>
```

Here is my Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#tblCustomersLocation').DataTable({
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'copyHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Create New Location'
                //action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                //    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
                //    $('#generalCusModal12').show();
                //}
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Edit Existing Location'
                //action: function (e, dt, node, config) {
                //    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
                //    $('#generalCusModal').modal('show');
                //}
            },
            {
                extend: 'csvHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Set Default Location'
            },
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                text: '',
                titleAttr: 'Refresh Records'
            }
        ],
        "paging": false,
        "info": false,
        "searching": false,
        "bAutoWidth": false
    });
});
```

BTW. the table is inside a panel, and the panel is inside a modal.